# How to recognize changes of a toggleSwitch

Tags: c#, blend

I try to handle cases depending on the current value of a toggleSwitch in Blend for Visual Studio 2015 with C#. I want to print the correct value to the debug output.

I have the following code

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true) {
            Debug.WriteLine("On");
        }
        else {
            Debug.WriteLine("Off");
        }
    }
}
```

The output prints correctly that the start state of the switch is off.
But if I change the value within the UI, the output stays off. No matter how often I change it.

What's the right way to recognize the value change and print it into the output?
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: That code will only execute when the page is instantiated.  The `toggleSwitch` should have an event it fires when its state changes.

Comment: would you please do me the favor and give me an example? I come from swift and am having a hard time finding a solution or example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void YourToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true){
        Debug.WriteLine("On");
    }
    else{
        Debug.WriteLine("OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to call that function anyhow? I implemented it, but there is no output.

Comment: In your designer file YourToggleSwitch.Toggled += new System.EventHandler(YourToggleSwitch_Toggled);

Comment: sorry that i didnt gave you an upvote back then. just caught up. thanks for your effort